# c++ boost lambda cout <<

Tags: c++, boost, lambda, std

Can anyone explain why this doesn't work:

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), std::cout << _1 << std::endl);
```

while the following works fine:

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), std::cout << _1 << '\n');
```

Comment: Post the error to help people understand the problem

Comment: What do you mean by "works/doesn't work"? Is there an error, wrong output, something else?

Comment: What is `v`? Where is the lambda?

Comment: Can you please list the headers you're using? Most people will not associate this code and the word 'lambda' with `boost::lambda`. When in fact, that is critical to understanding this question.

Comment: Note that endl is \n on UNIX/Linux, but \r\n on MS Windows. Perhaps the OS information is not available to the boost lambda operator<<.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the following error, or something similar:

> `error C2914: 'boost::lambda::operator <<' : cannot deduce template argument as function argument is ambiguous`

`std::endl` is in fact an unary [function template](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/endl/) of the following signature:

```
template <class charT, class traits>
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& endl (basic_ostream<charT,traits>& os);
```

Which means that when you type `<< std::endl` then in fact you request for the function's address. In case the function is overloaded/templated, the compiler can't tell which one you want unless it can be deduced based on the parameter's type. Since the lambda `operator<<` is a function template as well, there is no such possibility.

To work around that, you need to manually disambiguate the call using e.g. `static_cast`:

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(),
              std::cout << boost::lambda::_1
                        << static_cast<std::ostream&(*)(std::ostream&)>(std::endl));
```

Comment: The solution is correct, but I'm not sure about the arguments. It seems that the compiler fails to instantiate `endl` automatically, because the lambda functor itself is a template.

Comment: << std::endl is not a constant because it depends on the operating system.